# Use VBA to download zip file from url

Tags: vba, excel, download

I am using [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/984206-need-visual-basic-applications-download-copy-data-zip-file.html) as reference to download a zip file from url.

The code I am using is in below

```
Sub DownloadZipExtractCsvAndLoad()
  Dim UrlFile As String, ZipFile As String, CsvFile As String, Folder As String, s As String
  ' UrlFile to the ZIP archive
  UrlFile = "https://loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub/publish?file=2008Q1.zip"
  ' Extract ZipFile from UrlFile
  ZipFile = "2008Q1.zip"
  ' Define temporary folder
  Folder = "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\"
  ' Disable screen updating to avoid blinking
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ' Trap errors
  On Error GoTo exit_ 
  ' Download UrlFile to ZipFile in Folder
  If Not Url2File(UrlFile, Folder & ZipFile, "xxx", "xxxx") Then
    MsgBox "Can't download file" & vbLf & UrlFile, vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
  End If 
exit_:
  ' Restore screen updating
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
  ' Inform about the reason of the trapped error
  If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub

Function Url2File(UrlFile As String, PathName As String, Optional Login As String, Optional Password As String) As Boolean
'ZVI:2017-01-07 Download UrlFile and save it to PathName.
'               Use optional Login and Password if required.
'               Returns True on success downloading.
  Dim b() As Byte, FN As Integer
  On Error GoTo exit_
  If Len(Dir(PathName)) Then Kill PathName
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", UrlFile, False, Login, Password
    .send
    If .Status <> 200 Then Exit Function
    b() = .responseBody
    FN = FreeFile
    Open PathName For Binary Access Write As #FN
    Put #FN, , b()
exit_:
    If FN Then Close #FN
    Url2File = .Status = 200
  End With
End Function
```

However, every time I run the code, it will only create an empty zip file instead of downloading the file.

Any help?

Comment: If you go to the actual URL that you are trying to retrieve (i.e. paste **https://loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub/publish?file=2008Q1.zip** into your browser search bar), you will see that the file doens't exist.

Comment: @ainwood I am new to this area. That website requires login info. After I login with my username and password, the link works.

Answer (score -1):

i assume that you are able to get the file by using a web browser and logging in

it is the b() near the bottom

it should be:

```
b = fileObj.responseBody
.
.
Put #FN, , b
```

i tested it by retrieving *UrlFile = "https://www.google.ca/"*

i added a couple of lines to print the status after the file retrieve attempt

```
Sub DownloadZipExtractCsvAndLoad()

    Dim UrlFile As String, ZipFile As String, CsvFile As String, Folder As String, s As String


    UrlFile = "https://loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub/publish?file=2008Q1.zip"    ' UrlFile to the ZIP archive
    ZipFile = "2008Q1.zip"                                                                 ' Extract ZipFile from UrlFile

    UrlFile = "https://www.google.ca/"                   ' debug ... test url
    ZipFile = "2008Q1.html"                              ' debug ... test file

    Folder = "C:\Users\js135001\Desktop\"                                                  ' Define temporary folder
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                                     ' Disable screen updating to avoid blinking

'   On Error GoTo exit_err                                                                ' Trap errors

    If Not Url2File(UrlFile, Folder & ZipFile, "xxx", "xxxx") Then                         ' Download UrlFile to ZipFile in Folder
        MsgBox "Can't download file" & vbLf & UrlFile, vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

exit_err:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                                      ' Restore screen updating

    If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"                                ' Inform about the reason of the trapped error

End Sub

Function Url2File(UrlFile As String, PathName As String, Optional Login As String, Optional Password As String) As Boolean
    ' ZVI:2017-01-07 Download UrlFile and save it to PathName.
    '                Use optional Login and Password if required.
    '                Returns True on success downloading.

    Dim b() As Byte, FN As Integer

'   On Error GoTo exit_err

    If Len(Dir(PathName)) Then Kill PathName

    Dim httpObj As Object
    Set httpObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    httpObj.Open "GET", UrlFile, False, Login, Password
    httpObj.send

    Debug.Print httpObj.Status               ' debug
    Debug.Print httpObj.statusText           ' debug

    If httpObj.Status <> 200 Then Exit Function

    b = httpObj.responseBody
    FN = FreeFile
    Open PathName For Binary Access Write As #FN
    Put #FN, , b

'   Put #FN, , httpObj.responseBody    ' you could do this, and not use b() at all

exit_err:
    If FN Then Close #FN
    Url2File = (httpObj.Status = 200)               ' return true/false

End Function
```

Comment: When I test your code, the httpObj.Status is always 404. I am not sure whether it is cause by the URL or not. `loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub/publish?file=2008Q1.‌​zip` is the real download link. After I go to `https://loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub/index.html` and login, that link works. Otherwise it will say file doesn't exist.

Comment: @kzhang12, that webpage is password protected (use a web browser and you will see), that is why i included link to _https://www.google.ca/_ for testing. just comment out the first _"UrlFile = "_    line for testing.  i do not know how to add a password to the URL that returns a 404.

Comment: I am using the code to download zip file from https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2020/MAR/cm13MAR2020bhav.csv.zip url. But I keep getting error that 'The download of specified resource has failed'. Can someone help me ?